# how to use Stanford NLP (or other packages) to train my own coref (coreference resolution) model?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have texts similar to this: "This research was conducted as part of the Work, Family and Health Network (www.WorkFamilyHealthNetwork.org), which is funded by a cooperative agreement through the National Institutes of Health and the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention: Eunice Kennedy Shriver National Institute of Child Health and Human Development (Grant # U01HD051217, U01HD051218, U01HD051256, U01HD051276), National Institute on Aging (Grant # U01AG027669), Office of Behavioral and Science Sciences Research, and National Institute for Occupational Safety and Health (Grant # U01OH008788, U01HD059773)." I need to connect the funder with their grant number, e.g.: National Institutes of Health and the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention: Eunice Kennedy Shriver National Institute of Child Health and Human Development -- U01HD051217, U01HD051218, U01HD051256, U01HD051276         National Institute on Aging -- U01AG027669 . I am thinking this as a coreference resolution problem and trying to train my own model. Any idea how I can do this? I tried to follow the instructions from here (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html#training-new-models), but since they use the C0NLL dataset, I don't see how exactly I could convert my own data into their format. Anybody help please?

Answer (score -1):

`java -cp "*" -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file input.txt -outputFormat conll`

Above will give you the conll format data

Then you can get xml for coref and merge with the conll to get complete data